# Creating AICc table but keep getting aictab error: could not find function

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to create an AICc table but keep getting an error, "could not find function aictab"

```
Cand.mod<-list()
Cand.mod[[1]]<-lm(Diversity~Evenness, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[2]]<-lm(Diversity~Abundance, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[3]]<-lm(Diversity~Richness, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[4]]<-lm(Diversity~Abundance+Richness, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[5]]<-lm(Diversity~Abundance+Evenness, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[6]]<-lm(Diversity~Richness+Evenness, data=MATH620)
Cand.mod[[7]]<-lm(Diversity~1, data=MATH620)
Modnames<-c("Evenness", "Abudance", "Richness", "Abundance+Richness", "Abundance+Evenness", "Richness+Evenness", "Intercept-only")
aictab(cand.set=Cand.mod, modnames=Modnames)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the package the function aictab is from? The line isn't included in your code sample and it isn't a base R function. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AICcmodavg/versions/2.3-1/topics/aictab